# RenderControl from within WCF service fails; ASMX works

Tags: asp.net, wcf, dynamic, content-management-system

Good afternoon! I've spent half my day trying to figure this out; hopefully one of you can help.

I have written a limited CMS and am working on allowing content from the CMS to be displayed as interstitial pages within external sites. To do this, I wanted to create a WCF service that would render the appropriate content and return it as a string to be placed into the client page.

However, I've run into a strange behavior. The `RadioButtonList` and `CheckBoxList` controls end up throwing a `NullReferenceException` during `RenderControlInternal` (obviously not my contribution).  All other controls (textboxes, listboxes, dropdowns, custom composite controls) render fine.

I created an ASMX service alongside the WCF service, and cut/pasted the code directly from the WCF service. It renders the controls perfectly.

Any clues why the WCF service selectively causes bombs?

Here is the service method code:

```
    public string RenderPageContents(int pageId)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;

        SiteBuilder.Page p = new SiteBuilder.Page();
        if (p.Load(pageId))
        {
            foreach (SiteBuilder.PageItem pi in p.Items)
            {
                if (pi.LoadItemDetails(true))
                {
                    // Calls LoadControl from \Bin
                    Web.Controls.Base.BuilderControlBase bcb =
                          Web.Controls.ControlHelper.CreateSiteBuilderControl(
                              @"C:\Development\SitebuilderService\", 
                             pi.ItemDetails);

                    if (bcb != null)
                    {
                        bcb.Configure(pi);
                        output += ControlHelper.RenderControl(ref bcb);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Here is the code for `ControlHelper.RenderControl` (yes, it's in VB. It lives in another project).

```
Public Shared Function RenderControl(ByRef ctrl As Controls.Base.BuilderControlBase) _
      As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim tw As New StringWriter(sb)
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(tw)

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw)

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

The exception message is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is a stacktrace of the Exception thrown when WCF is used:

```
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at XXX.ControlHelper.RenderControl(BuilderControlBase& ctrl) 
    in C:\TFS\XXX\Development\XXX\Web\Controls\Builder\Helpers\ControlHelper.vb:line 81 
at XXX.Services.SiteBuilderService.RenderPageContents(Int32 pageId) 
    in C:\TFS\Development\XXX.Web.Services\XXX.Web.Services\SiteBuilderService.svc.cs:line 61
```

---

> Does the WCF service return the correct string when called separately?

I'm not sure I understand your exact meaning. Separately from what? If I call the business class that does the processing from a test harness, yes it works correctly. When I call it from an ASMX service it works properly. From WCF, radiobutton rendering breaks.

> What kind of binding and security do you use for the WCF service?

I'm using basicHttpBinding.

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISiteBuilderService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="1024000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="1024000" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>


<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISiteBuilderService" contract="SiteBuilder.ISiteBuilderService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISiteBuilderService" />

<service behaviorConfiguration="Xxx.SiteBuilderServiceBehavior"
   name="Xxx.Services.SiteBuilderService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Kaplan.OEC.Services.ISiteBuilderService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

<behavior name="Xxx.Services.SiteBuilderServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
```

> If you call the service in e.g. SoapUI - does it return the string in the expected format? Or maybe some tags and/or special characters might get mangled up?

From SoapUI it also fails to render properly, the same error occurs as from WCF.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried turning on [ASP.NET compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) in your WCF configuration? The error is likely related to the HttpContext not being available (though if I may say it, your current approach, while probably workable, is rather ugly :-))

Comment: I suspect this might be the issue.  I opened up System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList.Render using .NET Reflector and found this code: "If (Not MyBase.DesignMode AndAlso Not Me.Context.Request.Browser.Tables) Then".  Looking into Context, if page.Context is null, it returns HttpContext.Current.

Comment: Or since most of the question was posted in C#: if (!base.DesignMode && !this.Context.Request.Browser.Tables)

Answer (score 0):

Does the WCF service return the correct string when called separately? What kind of binding and security do you use for the WCF service? Can you post some configs (server-side, and possibly client side)?

The binding that would be closest to the ASMX legacy service would be `basicHttpBinding` with basically all security turned off. Are you using that?

If you call the service in e.g. SoapUI - does it return the string in the expected format? Or maybe some tags and/or special characters might get mangled up?